# simulating browser cache on my web application

Tags: javascript, html

so i have a website and i want to build a mechanism to simulate browser cache. meaning, for example i can get, for low cost, all the images that a page contains but not via http request via other protocol.
i want to be able to save those images(the one that i got ahead) within the memory of the browser (indexDB,applicationCache etc.) and then when i render the page not to load them from http, but from my cache.

notes: 
1) i prefer a way where i dont need to change the .html and src attr
2) i can also get the entire page ahead and not only the photos and maybe make some manipulations.

any idea's?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question let me elaborate.
the thing that would do the job best(but not possible) would be if i could manually save in browser cache, so when i get a photo via other protocol i just save it with the right key.
i want to simulate such act. meaning, have all the photos in memory (maybe indexDb) and when a call for some page is triggered, i need to check what i have in cache and get it from there, what i dont have, needs to come from http.
i can also presave an entire page on my memory and then when a this page is calles get is from memory(if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/) which abstracts different browser storage capabilities in to a common interface. Acts like localStorage and has several back-ends (like cookies, flash storage etc.). You can store them here and check them out if they exist here.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question let me elaborate.
the thing that would do the job best(but not possible) would be if i could manually save in browser cache, so when i get a photo via other protocol i just save it with the right key.
i want to simulate such act. meaning, have all the photos in memory (maybe indexDb) and when a call for some page is triggered, i need to check what i have in cache and get it from there, what i dont have, needs to come from http.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) on html5 cache. you need to create the cache manifest file and write your images path in the #cache section of manifest file. put the reference of file in each .html/.htm file header.

Comment: I do not want the browser to cache the photos for me. i have the photos already in memory. and want to load them from memory and not from server(i got the photos via other protocol). i want to detect what photos i have in memory and for load them somehow from memory(my cache and not browser cache) instead of http when rendering the page